# can i make Scoreboard in sfml/c++?

Tags: c++, sfml

i tried to use filestream in it and it saves the highestscore only nut the name change even if the score was < the highstscore

```
if (event.type == Event::TextEntered) {

    if (event.text.unicode == '\b') // handle backspace explicitly
    {
        plyname.erase(plyname.size() - 1, 1);
        pl2_name.setString(plyname);
    }
    else // all other keypresses
    {
        plyname += static_cast<char>(event.text.unicode);
        if ((event.text.unicode < 128) && (plyname.size() < 8))
            pl2_name.setString(plyname);
    }
}
outfile.open("data/highscore.txt");
if (outfile.is_open()) {
    if (SCore_pl > HIGHSCORE) {
        HIGHSCORE = SCore_pl;

    }
    outfile << HIGHSCORE << plyname;
}
outfile.close();
```

how can i fix this to make leadernoard ?

Comment: So is your code overwriting the file instead of appending text to it?

Comment: its overwriting even if the score is 0 
i want it to over write only if the SCore_pl > HIGHSCORE

Answer (score 1):

Try that checking before opening the file

```
...
if (SCore_pl > HIGHSCORE) {
   outfile.open("data/highscore.txt");
   if (outfile.is_open()) {
        HIGHSCORE = SCore_pl; 
    outfile << HIGHSCORE << plyname; 
   }
   outfile.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the `outfile << HIGHSCORE <<plyname;` into the if statement

Comment: did you put your the code into the 'if ( SCore_pl > HIGHSCORE)' statement?

Comment: try to print out score and highscore